# PHP - Best Way To Handle Multiple database in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, zend-framework2, zend-db

We are creating a web application using Zend Framework 2 with multiple databases. I have a `core` database which loads info of all customers. This database contains `customer` table. The fields of customer table are ::

1. id
2. username
3. password
4. database_name
5. customer_name
6. ...................

When a customers logs in, i have to load his database name from the `core` database and then make query requests to the database.

I cannot have multiple adapters either, because all customers have their own database which i have to load from `customer` table of `core_db`!

I thought i would prefix database name with table name.

I tried this in `Module.php`:

```
"CategoryTableGateway" => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get("Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter");
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Category());
                return new TableGateway("databasename.category", $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            }
```

I had configured default database in my `config\autoload\database.global.php` as this:

```
    'db' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=core_db;host=localhost',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
)
```

I got a exception like:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'core_db.databasename.category' doesn't exist.
```

And then, I removed `dbname=core_db` from `config\autoload\database.global.php`.

Now, I got another exception like:

```
SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
```

So how do i handle that situation in Zend Framework 2. I am new to Zend Framework 2.

`Edit`: I got the solution to my question by myself.

To connect to table of another schema you need to pass `TableIdentifier` instead of table!

For example,

Instead of:

```
 $CategoryTableGateway = new TableGateway("category", $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
```

You have to do:

```
$CategoryTableIdentifier = new TableIdentifier('category','dbname');
$CategoryTableGateway = new TableGateway($CategoryTableIdentifier, $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
```

Hope It Works!

Answer (score -1):

> When a customers logs in, i have to load his database name from the core database and then make query requests to the database.

This is what you are doing wrong.

Just keep everything in single database, like very e-commerce site in the world does.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Can you give some examples? That would be appreciated.

Comment: Forget the E-commerce part. I have changed the question. It was my mistake. My question is more about handing multiple databases!

Comment: it doesn't matter. You don't understand the meaning of database and inventing a square wheel. Just use one. That's all.

Comment: That means I have to user where "customer_id=$id" in all query.

Comment: yes, exactly. that's what you have to do. not $id but customer_id=? it have to be though

Comment: @YourCommonSense: I'm surprised to read such answer from you. This is a perfectly valid question, and multiple-users/mono-database or multiple-users/multiple-database problems have some problems to deal with (number of persistent conn, app code), but also some advantages (database based privilege managment, ro/rw separations and load balancing, etc). The easy answer is to avoid complex things. But that's not the answer I would expect from an expert like you. Or at least could you provide real details on why managing several database connections would be bad by nature?